# 2023-06-22T17:34:48.453+0700 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, android-studio-2.2

I had problem with running my project in android studio. I have ever searched this in google and everywhere can fix this but its can't fix it. pls help me
i run it in android studio flamingo version

[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]

```
2023-06-22T17:34:48.453+0700 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

this is my file build.gradle:app:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
android {
    namespace 'com.example.product2'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.product2"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        viewBinding = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
}
```

and this is my file build.gradle:project:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        agp_version = '8.0.0'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

i want sb can help me to find solutions for this. I have tried it so many times

Comment: Is that the complete error log you received?